# Average of n rows while keeping the data of the first row (of every n rows) in r

Tags: r

My data looks similar to this:

```
value    days
  25       1
  24       2
  25       4
  26       5
```

I'd like to calculate the avarage of every n rows of the value column, but to keep the "days" information of every first row, every n rows. For example, for n=2, the new data will look accordingly:

```
 value    days
  24.5     1
  25.5     4
```

When I use colMeans I only get the value column.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

say your `data.frame` is called `df`

```
library(plyr)
n <- 2
ddply(df, .(rep(1:(nrow(df)/n), each=n)), summarise, mean=mean(value), day=days[1])
```

**EDIT:**

you can also provide more variable to subset() your `df`, just put them inside `.()` separated by commas like `.(var1, var2, var3)` or, to give the names to these variables,  `.(newname1=var1, newname2=var2, newname3=var3)`. In your example:

```
> ddply(df, .(groupID=rep(1:(nrow(df)/n), each=n)), summarise, mean=mean(value), day=days[1])
  groupID mean day
1       1 24.5   1
2       2 25.5   4
```